# can't set portTypeName in axistools-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-2, axis, porttype

It seems that the portTypeName  parameter of the axistools-maven-plugin (version 1.3) cannot be set.
The classOfPortType parameter is a required parameter and cannot be omitted but when setting it alongside portTypeName  the following error appear:

Embedded error: Java2WSDL execution failed
invalid parameters, can not use portTypeName and classOfPortType together

I see there is  Jira issue [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAXISTOOLS-24). Is there a workaround?

Ronen.